# How to implement a refresh status in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to do a refresh status in which if the page was refreshed under 5 minutes, it would say "Updated Just Now," and if it was updated over 5 minutes ago, it would say, "Updated Moments Ago." Below is my Javascript:

```
var startTime, endTime;

function start() {
  startTime = performance.now();
};
function end() {
  endTime = performance.now();
  var timeDiff = endTime - startTime; //in ms 
  // strip the ms 
  timeDiff /= 1000;
  var seconds = Math.round(timeDiff);
if (seconds < 10) {
    time = "Updated Just Now";
  } else {
    time = "Updated Moments Ago";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = time;    
}

window.onload = start
window.onload = end
```

However, it is very buggy and sometimes doesn't work at all. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You're overwriting `window.onload` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I missed something, I think You can use setTimeout. Initially set the HTML to 'Updated just now'.

```
const timeout = 5 * 60 * 1000
const changeText = () => {
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Updated moments ago";
}
setTimeout(changeText, timeout)
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-https-f9lys?file=/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this instead of doing that stuff.

```
/* Note That 1000 is equivalent of 1 seconds */

setTimeout(function(){ 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Updated Just Now";
}, 30000); /* This value is equivalent of 30 seconds */

setTimeout(function(){ 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Updated Moments Ago";
}, 300000); /* This value is equivalent of 5 minutes */
```